# Flutter/Firebase Auth Error when deployed to Android Device

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter application with Firebase Auth instrumented.

It works fine on the Android emulators.

My problem occurs when I have deployed to an Amazon Fire Tablet (NOT a Kindle device).

I have looked at similar issues here and most answers are from 2018 or earlier and seem to be related to a version conflict.

Development Environments:  VS Code and Android Studio   (both recent installs less that 2 weeks old)

Pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  provider: ^4.3.1
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
```

The error is:

> I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 6110): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
> returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@23afde4
> W/DynamiteModule( 6110): Local module descriptor class for
> com.google.firebase.auth not found. W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 6110):
> Google Play Store is missing. I/flutter ( 6110):
> PlatformException(ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE, API:
> InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this
> device. Connection failed with:
> ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null,
> message=null}, null) I/flutter ( 6110): sign in error

Comment: Your app relies on Google Play Store and can't be used on Kindle Fires unless you install Google Play store.

Comment: More specifically, your app requires Google Play Services to be installed on the device. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms